# How to highlight data points that are out of a predefined range in Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

My data table has the following structure:

| Batch ID | Value | Upper limit | Lower limit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 4 | 6 | 3 |
| 1235 | 7 | 5 | 3.5 |

I have the batches on the X-axis for comparison and show the measured "Value" for each of them on a scatter plot. Additionally, I would like to find a way to highlight if this value is out of the individual tolerance range (upper and lower limit).

I tried combined axes, colouring rules and line/curve drawing, but could not find a way to show what we need. Colouring rules work with fixed values only, combined axes need to be hierarchical, lines don't work well with categorical values.
Maybe whiskers would be possible somehow? Or do I have to transform the data table?

Answer (score 0):

Can you colour by this Custom Expression? When in the Colors property, right click on the selection just below Columns on top and choose Custom Expression..., then type the following

```
([Value]>[Upper limit]) or ([Value]<[Lower limit])
```

This gives you True/False values that you can assign colours to.